# Finding the highest 12 continuous values in range

Tags: excel

I have data spread across rows and columns and I would like to find the range of 12 cells next to each with the highest value. Where next to each other means left to right and then starting on the next row. i.e. `A5, B5, ..., L5, A6, B6, ...`

[image: data]

I could specify all possible ranges i.e. `A5:L5, B5:A6...` sum and compare but this does not seem like a very efficient way of going about things.

How to go about this?

Comment: so "next to each other" really means "in reading sequence - Left to Right - Top to Bottom" ?

Comment: from Left to Right - Top to Bottom - I have edited the question for, hopefully, greater clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try. You simply highlight the range, and the message box returns the start position of the 12 integer array.

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim rng As Range

    Dim FC As Integer
    Dim LC As Integer
    Dim FR As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim maxI As Integer
    Dim maxCol As Integer
    Dim maxRow As Integer

    Dim intArray() As Integer

    Set rng = Selection

    FC = rng.Column
    FR = rng.Row
    LC = FC + rng.Columns.Count - 1
    LR = FR + rng.Rows.Count - 1

    ReDim intArray(1 To (LC * LR))

    i = 1

    For r = FR To LR
        For c = FC To LC
        intArray(i) = Cells(r, c)
        i = i + 1
        Next c
    Next r

    max = 0

    For i = 1 To (UBound(intArray) - 11)
        k = 0
        k = intArray(i)
        For j = 1 To 11
            k = k + intArray(i + j)
        Next j
        If k > max Then
            max = k
            maxI = i
        End If
    Next i

    maxCol = maxI Mod (rng.Columns.Count)
    maxRow = ((maxI - maxCol) / rng.Columns.Count) + 1

    MsgBox ("Max array begins in row " & maxRow & " column " & maxCol)


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Let me know if this isn't right

Comment: If you plan to run large arrays, you may need to change all the integer references to long.